# Add Content To Dynamically, Angular Promise Created Elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I have a map which uses an Angular Service to get data. The data is passed to a function which loops through it creating markers. Each loop calls a function which **should** create a popup for each marker, but shows up blank.

When I log the popup content to the console, it shows up after a few seconds, but I can't figure out how to pass it to the marker. I have a feeling it's something to do with closures, which I have been investigating. This is my code:

```
    //Create the Markers Function
var createMapMarkers = function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {

        //Calling the get popup content function here
        var content = getPopupContent(value.AreaName, value.ImageUrl);

        var marker = L.marker([value.Lat, value.Long])
        .bindPopup(content)
        .addTo($scope.map);
    });
}

function getPopupContent(areaName, imageUrl) {
    var response;
        $http.get('/Home/GetPopupContent?areaName=' + areaName + '&imageUrl=' + imageUrl)
        .then(function (response) {
            //This logs the correct content
            console.log(response);
        });
    //But it does not return here
        return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the promise from your `getPopupContent` method, and then you can work on the result when it is ready. As it is, you are just calling a promise and returning `undefined`.

```
var createMapMarkers = function (data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {

        //Calling the get popup content function here
        getPopupContent(value.AreaName, value.ImageUrl).then(function(content) {
            var marker = L.marker([value.Lat, value.Long])
                         .bindPopup(content)
                         .addTo($scope.map);
        });
    });
}

function getPopupContent(areaName, imageUrl) {
    return $http.get('/Home/GetPopupContent?areaName=' + areaName + '&imageUrl=' + imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: This has been eluding me for about two months, it's makes perfect sense now, thanks a lot.